# Prevent CompletionItem list from inserting first value

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have a snippet:

```js
'color: ${1|initial,inherit|};'
```

Which is registered like so (minus unnecessery code):

```js
const cssPropertyProvider = languages.registerCompletionItemProvider('mjml', {
  provideCompletionItems(document, position) {
    const snippetCompletion = new CompletionItem(attr.prefix)

    snippetCompletion.documentation = new MarkdownString(attr.description)
    snippetCompletion.insertText = new SnippetString(attr.body)

    return snippetCompletion
  }
})

subscriptions.push(cssPropertyProvider)
```

This automatically inserts the first list item (`initial`) when selecting the CompletionItem:

[image]

Is there a way to prevent this?

---

Essentially, I want the same functionality as a placeholder, but with a list:

```js
'color: ${1:initial};'
```

[image]

---

[VSCode docs on lists and placeholders](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_snippet-syntax) 
[VSCode docs on `registerCompletionItemProvider`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#languages.registerCompletionItemProvider)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to abandon the list/placeholder way and store the suggestions separately:

```js
body: 'color: $1;',
values: ['initial', 'inherit'],
```

Then, assign this command to the original suggestion (`cssPropertyProvider`):

```js
snippetCompletion.command = {
    command: 'editor.action.triggerSuggest',
    title: '',
}
```

And add a separate completion provider to cover this:

```js
const cssValueProvider = languages.registerCompletionItemProvider('mjml', {
    provideCompletionItems(document, position) {
        const snippetCompletions: ProviderResult<CompletionItem[] | CompletionList> = []

        cssProperties.forEach((prop) => {
            const formattedBody = prop.body.split('$1').join('')

            // Ensure the line includes the relevant CSS property
            if (!document.lineAt(position).text.includes(formattedBody)) return

            prop.values.forEach((val) => {
                const snippetCompletion = new CompletionItem(val)

                // Sets the suggestion icon to the little orange thing
                snippetCompletion.kind = 11 // 11 = Value
                // Ensure tab-stops ($1) are handled
                snippetCompletion.insertText = new SnippetString(val)

                snippetCompletions.push(snippetCompletion)
            })
        })

        return snippetCompletions
    },
})
```

Also, just for my specific use case, I had to add a check in `cssPropertyProvider` that prevents the property suggestions displaying above the value suggestions:

```js
const cssPropertyProvider = languages.registerCompletionItemProvider('mjml', {
    provideCompletionItems(document, position) {
        const { text: lineText } = document.lineAt(position)
        const lastLineChar = lineText[position.character]

        if (lastLineChar === ';') return
...
```

---

**Result:**

[image]